# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable disnake sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, disnake

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_dropdown(self, inter: disnake.MessageInteraction):
    c = self.conn.cursor()
    c.execute(f"SELECT role_id, cost FROM shop WHERE id = ?", (inter.data['values'][0],))
    row = c.fetchone()
    role = inter.guild.get_role(row[0])
    if role in inter.author.roles:
        embed = disnake.Embed(title="Магазин ролей", description=f"У вас уже есть роль {role}", color=0xFF0000)
        await inter.response.send_message(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)
        return
    if c.execute(f"SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {inter.author.id}") < row[1]:
        embed = disnake.Embed(title="Магазин ролей", description=f"У вас недостаточно денег для покупки роли {role_name}", color=0xFF0000)
        await inter.response.send_message(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)
        return
    else:
        c.execute(f"UPDATE users SET cash = {c.execute(f'SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {inter.author.id}') - row[1]} WHERE id = {inter.author.id}")
        self.conn.commit()
        await inter.author.add_roles(role)
        embed = disnake.Embed(title="Магазин ролей", description=f"Вы успешно приобрели роль {role}", color=0x2f3136)
        await inter.response.send_message(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)
```

```
    role_id = row[0]
              ~~~^^^
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

ну типа не доходит до меня почему row[0] обращается к None объекту?

Comment: Ошибка значит, что в `row` у вас `None`. Видимо, `SQL` запрос ничего вам не вернул. Почему - разбирайтесь. Что за таблица `shop`, что в ней означает `id`, какого типа это поле `id`, какого типа данные вы передали для подстановки в `id` и т.д.